# Use futures from a list as soon as they are complete (without waiting for the rest of them)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I have a method returning a `Seq[Future[Any]]`. I am using Akka Cluster, and this method is sending messages to several nodes. Sometimes one of my node processes would terminate, and my code would just stand there waiting for the futures to complete.

Basically I just want to provide the UI with completed futures as soon as they are available. Is there a way I can extract the completed futures from that `Seq[Future[Any]]` right away?

Comment: If I understand you well, adding timeout on time you wait for response from remote node should help? Or, please, provide mode details on problem.

Comment: How about simply `seq.foreach { _.onComplete(result => notifyUI(result)) }` ?

Comment: @Evgeny,  I already have a timeout, waiting for a `Future[Seq[Any]]`. But I don't want the UI to be waiting for the timeout. I will give it a go to @Kolmar 's suggestion.

Comment: Add some code, please. Makes it easier to answer

Comment: Have you tried `val x: Seq[Future[Any]] = Seq(); x.filter(_.isCompleted)`?